# Any netbeans plugin that would log file changes?

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I would like to maintain a log of changes made to all files of a project while working in a Netbeans session. This would be useful to undo/review changes made while debugging the project.

Is there any plugin that would maintain a log of such file changes ?

*I use Netbeans 7.2. for Java Projects.*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a real version control system. There are [plugins for NetBeans](https://versioncontrol.netbeans.org/).  I've yet to see some automated system appropriately handle the task of source code change tracking.

Comment: I do use Subversion & Local History plugins but here I'm asking something different, I need to have a "common change log" for all files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for quick/temporary use:
Download and install Netbeans plugin 'Local History' through `Tools->Plugin`. After you reload your IDE and save a file multiple times, you'll be able to see a `History` view for your file. You can see differences between the revisions, restore etc.

If you want maintain revisions and permanent use, I would recommend using "git".

Comment: I know & use both of them, I m asking something different here, I want a "common change log" for all files.